# Counting multiple values from a query

Tags: php

I'm getting an array of this type from the database: (I can't change the type of data received, as it comes from an outside source)

```
Array
(
[0] => Es\Result Object
    (
        [_hit:protected] => Array
            (
                [_index] => website
                [_type] => structure
                [_id] => 8
                [_score] => 0.625
                [_source] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Test1
                        [locality] => Array
                            (
                                [locality] => Bologna
                                [sign] => BO
                                [province] => Array
                                    (
                                        [province] => Bologna
                                        [region] => Array
                                            (
                                                [region] => Emilia Romagna
                                            )

                                    )

                            )
                    )
            )
    )
[1] => Elastica\Result Object
    (
        [_hit:protected] => Array
            (
                [_index] => website
                [_type] => structure
                [_id] => 6
                [_score] => 0.625
                [_source] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Test2
                        [locality] => Array
                            (
                                [locality] => Bologna
                                [sign] => BO
                                [province] => Array
                                    (
                                        [province] => Bologna
                                        [region] => Array
                                            (
                                                [region] => Emilia Romagna
                                            )

                                    )

                            )
                    )

            )

    )
    ......
```

I enter into a json object value of "locality" and count how many "locality" are equal, for example:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $source = $result->getSource();
    $locality = $source['locality']['locality'];
    $dataLocality[] = array(
        'type'    => 'locality',
        'label'   => $locality,
        'count'   => 1, //How to increase the count here?
    );
}
```

I tried to put everything in a loop but I can't count the values ​​correctly.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

This should be the result that I get:

let's say I get the array has 3 "locality":

2 "foo"

1 "bar"

```
$dataLocality = 
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [type] => 'locality'
           [locality] => 'foo'
           [count] => 2
       )
   [1] => Array
       (
           [type] => 'locality'
           [locality] => 'bar'
           [count] => 1
       )
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to increment the count for each data added?

Comment: Yes, I have to count how many there are equal values ​​in the array that I get. For example, if the item "locality" there are 2 arrays with "foo" and one array with "bar" in my array "dataLocality" I'll have an array with label "foo" and count 2, and one array with label "bar "and count 1.

Comment: Please explain what you try to achieve as result.

Comment: I've updated the question with the result that I get .

Answer (score 0):

Does the value of $locality exist in the array?  If no, then store it with a count of 1.  If yes, then add 1 to the count.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $source = $result->getSource();
    $locality = $source['locality']['locality'];
    // Manually specify the array key. This makes life much easier down the road,
    // especially when you need to find items in the array.
    if ( !isset($dataLocality[$locality]) ) {
        $dataLocality[$locality] = array('type'    => 'locality',
                                         'label'   => $locality,
                                         'count'   => 1);
    } else {
        $dataLocality[$locality]['count'] += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't create an array with key "locality", I have to turn that array into json object and must be a number.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array (say `$dataLocality`) outside your foreach loop. In each loop you search for an existant locality in `$datalocality` (if `$result` is in `$dataLocality`). If there is one, you increment the counter by `$dataLocality[$indexOfFounding]['count']++`.

This off course requires the adding of your array of 'type', 'label' and 'count' if you don't find any locality in $dataLocality.

After the foreach loop you can go through your array and output or do anything with your results.

Comment: Thank you, but this is already what I do, the problem is how to do it because I can't find a way to count the values​​. 
I've updated my question with the result that I get. 
You may supplement your answer with a possible solution? thanks

Comment: There's no way to output a result in the middle of a loop, if you dont't know if there are localities in the end of the array which you also have to count. So, you have go through your array and after that, do something with your count results. 
What do you want to achieve? Increase of Performance?

Comment: Yes, since responses are to be given to a field of search autocomplete.
But at the moment I can't find a solution that works, not even slow ..!

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing the count of locality array then make use of `count` Try:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $source = $result->getSource();
    $locality = $source['locality']['locality'];
    $dataLocality[] = array(
        'type'    => 'locality',
        'label'   => $locality,
        'count'   => count($source['locality']), //get locality array count
    );
}
```

Comment: Inside 'locality' there are several locality, such as 2 locality "foo" and 1 locality "bar". I don't have to count the total locality , but many are the same locality.

Comment: So what do you exactly need? locality foo count 2 and bar count 1?

Comment: foo and bar are examples. 
I need to count equal values​​, I edited my question to make it clear what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dave's reply I solved the problem, but since I could not have named keys, I added outside the loop:

```
$dataLocality = array_values($dataLocality);
```

so the complete code to solve the problem, but on occasions someone had a problem similar to mine is:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $source = $result->getSource();
    if(!isset($dataLocality[$locality = $source['locality']['locality']])) {
        $dataLocality[$locality] = array(
            'type'    => 'locality',
            'label'   => $locality,
            'count'   => 1,
        );
    } else {
        $dataLocality[$locality]['count']++;
    }
}
$dataLocality = array_values($dataLocality);
```